# Dojo reading JSON data without an Identifier

Tags: json, dojo

I'm trying to parse a JSON from a rest service. This service does not put the data into the format that I think ItemFileReadStore wants, but I cannot change it. Everything I have found in the dojo library for reading JSON data requires an identifier, which my data does not have. This is the JSON data:

```
  {"ChannelReadResponse":[
     {"Event":    {"@entityOrigin":"System","@entityId":"0x080e00000136ad8986520af104608052","Name":"Untitled","SymbolCode":"OHVPEV---------","TimeObserved":"2012-04-13T21:09:49.207Z","CreatedUser":"Helpdesk","ModifiedUser":"Helpdesk","CreatedTime":"2012-04-13T21:09:49.207Z","ModifiedTime":"2012-04-17T15:51:12.496Z"},
```

{"@entityOrigin":"System","@entityId":"0x080e00000136bb54ec770af104608028","Name":"My Event","SymbolCode":"OHVPE----------","Severity":"SIGACT","Outcome":"Effective","TimeObserved":"2012-04-16T14:34:29.796Z","CreatedUser":"Helpdesk","ModifiedUser":"Helpdesk","CreatedTime":"2012-04-16T14:34:29.796Z","ModifiedTime":"2012-04-17T15:50:52.499Z"}
]
,"Channel":{"@writable":"false","@connected":"true","@entityId":"0x080e00000136ad8500760af104608064","Name":"Ozone",
    "Members":{"Member":[{"@entityOrigin":"System","@entityRef":"0x080e00000136ad8986520af104608052"},{"@entityOrigin":"System","@entityRef":"0x080e00000136bb54ec770af104608028"}]
}}},
  {"Event": {"@entityOrigin":"System","@entityId":"0x080e00000136bc3c92d80af104608042","Name":"From2","SymbolCode":"OHVPE----------","TimeObserved":"2012-04-16T19:43:03.150Z","CreatedUser":"Helpdesk","ModifiedUser":"Helpdesk","CreatedTime":"2012-04-16T19:43:03.150Z","ModifiedTime":"2012-04-16T19:43:03.150Z"},
   "Channel":    {"@writable":"false","@connected":"true","@entityId":"0x080e00000136bc3c92d80af104608034","Name":"Ozone2",
    "Members":{"Member":{"@entityOrigin":"System","@entityRef":"0x080e00000136bc3c92d80af104608042"}}}
]}
]}

Is there any way to work with this data? I specifically want all the Events out of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just massage it into the form that the store wants. For example, if you get the data back in a variable called 'data', you could easily just do:

```
    var json = {
        identifier: "@entityId",
        items: data
    };
```

Then just use the `json` object in the store.

Answer (score 0):

I can only think of converting your JSON data to JavaScript Object Literal and then add the ID and Name to the JavaScript Object Literal....then convert it into JSON before passing it to your Dojo Store.

I have faced similar issue but i had the luxury to change my service to return JSON with Identifier and Name. I haven't tried what I wrote above.